# Pass method reference as an async call in Dart

Tags: asynchronous, dart

Is it possible to pass an `async` method as an `async` call in Dart?

For example, if I want to simplify this code:

```dart
...

void myFunc() async {
  await myLib.work();
}

...

RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () async { await myFunc(); },
)
```

to this:

```dart
...

void myFunc() async {
  await myLib.work();
}

...

RaisedButton(
  onPressed: myFunc,
)
```

Passing `myFunc` just as a reference and still maintain that each time `myFunc` is called from `onPressed` as a callback, it will be an asynchronous call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: Yes. The two pieces of code that you show are almost completely equivalent. Both call `myLib.work` and complete a future when the call's asynchronous computation completes.
You could probably also just write:

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: myLib.work, 
)
```

and it would still do the same thing.

However, I am not absolutely sure I understand what you mean by an "asynchronous call".

Dart function objects are not split into asynchronous functions and non-asynchronous functions that are called differently. They *can* be split into those returning `Future`s and those which don't, but you *call* them the same way. I assume that `myLib.work` returns a `Future`. You may then choose to `await` the result, but that's not part of the call.

*Calling* a function is not itself asynchronous, it's always synchronous - it returns a value before computation continues. That value might be a `Future` which will be completed later when an asynchronous computation has completed, but the *function* returns synchronously.

So, when you bind a `void Function()` method to the `onPressed` event, it will eventually call that function, ignore the return value, and continue synchronously.

If that function is `myLib.work`, then it calls `myLib.work` and ignores the returned `Future`. When the asynchronous work of `work` is done, it will complete the returned future, which nobody will notice.

If the function is `myFunc`, then it calls `myFunc` which immediately calls `myLib.work` and remembers the returned future. Then `myFunc` synchronously returns a new `Future` (which is ignored) and starts waiting (because of the `await`) on the future returned by `myLib.work`. When that future completes the `await` is done, and then the `myFunc` body is done, and finally the new `Future` is also completed. Again, nobody notices.

If the function is `() async => await myFunc()` then that function is called. It immediately calls `myFunc`, which immediately calls `myLib.work`, which returns a `Future` that `myFunc` starts waiting for and then returns a `Future`, which the function expression starts waiting for and then returns a `Future`, which is then ignored.
Eventually all these functions are completed, and nobody notices.

"If a future completes and nobody is listening, does it make an event?"

Comment: Hmm.... I guess my whole confusion is due to the lack of documentation on `Future`s that are not waited, just created and left for the event loop to process them. All the docs I have seen always have an `await` or a `then`.